# PHP MySQL $_POST

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a PHP form using MySQL database.
I have created a dropdown list with the names of samples (like Al, Au...) and a textbox for the values.
My problem that the units are in my database sometimes in ppm, sometimes in pph. 
How can I set if the values are in pph, use the $value=$_POST["value"]/10000;
if the values are in ppm,  use $value=$_POST["value"]?
Any idea?

My code:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["sample"]))
{
    $sample = $_POST["sample"];
    $unit   = mysql_query("SELECT unit FROM analysis where sample='" . $sample . "'");
    if ($unit == 'pph')
    {
        $value  = $_POST["value"] / 10000;
        $sql    = "SELECT
                       a.sample,
                       concat (a.modif, (IF (unit='pph',10000*value,value))),
                       a.method,
                       a.mkey,
                       b.name,
                       b.from,
                       b.to,
                       b.type
                  FROM
                       anlysis a,
                       sample b
                  WHERE
                        a.mkey=b.mkey AND sample = '$sample' AND value > '$value'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
    }
    else
    {
        $value  = $_POST["value"];
        $sql    = "SELECT
                        a.sample,
                        concat ( a.modif, ( IF (unit = 'pph', 10000 * value, value) ) ),
                        a.method,
                        a.mkey,
                        b.name,
                        b.from,
                        b.to,
                        b.type
                  FROM
                        anlysis a,
                        sample b
                  WHERE
                        a.mkey = b.mkey AND sample = '$sample' AND value > '$value'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
    }
```

}

Thank you!

Comment: Start with not using `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: Wooo ready to get lots of injections. $sample=INJECT_MY_SYSTEM

Comment: please try indent the code

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Comment: Yes, you are right I am new with PHP but everyone starts somewhere :) I will check PDO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I'd suggest:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["sample"])) {
$sample = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST["sample"])); //A little clean-up wont hurt...
$unit   = mysql_query("SELECT unit FROM analysis where sample='" . $sample . "'");
if ($unit == 'pph'){
    $postVal= htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST["value"]));
    $value  = $postVal / 10000;
    $sql    = "SELECT    a.sample,
                   concat (a.modif, (IF (unit='pph',10000*value, value))),
                   a.method,
                   a.mkey,
                   b.name,
                   b.from,
                   b.to,
                   b.type
              FROM
                   analysis AS a
              LEFT JOIN sample AS b
                   ON a.mkey=b.mkey
              WHERE
                    a.sample='" . $sample . "' AND a.value > '" . $value ."'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
}
else
{
    $postVal= htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST["value"]));
    $value  = $postVal;
    $sql    = "SELECT
                    a.sample,
                    concat ( a.modif, ( IF (unit = 'pph', 10000 * value, value) ) ),
                    a.method,
                    a.mkey,
                    b.name,
                    b.from,
                    b.to,
                    b.type
              FROM
                   analysis AS a
              LEFT JOIN sample AS b
                   ON a.mkey=b.mkey
              WHERE
                    a.mkey = b.mkey AND sample = '" . $sample . "' AND value > '" . $value . "'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I've tried it and it has worked! I am new with PHP so I have to learn a lot...Thank you again :)

Comment: I am glad it worked for you ;-)
You can just choose the answer as correct and mark it complete...

Answer (score 0):

first

```
$analysis = mysql_fetch_object($query);
```

then you can access the value

```
if ($analysis->unit == 'pph')
```